# Can I make (DirectoryIndex) in .htaccess file variable with current directory?

Tags: .htaccess, directoryindex

I know i can use
`DirectoryIndex index.php products.php` for default files.

But,is it possible to make it variable with current folder so it will be something like this :

```
DirectoryIndex CurrentFolderName.php
```

or appending some text like :

```
DirectoryIndex CurrentFolderName+123.php
```

so this will make the default file as the following :

> for www.mysite.com/products/ it will be (products.php or products123.php)
>
> for www.mysite.com/about-us/ it will be (about-us.php or about-us123.php)
>
> for www.mysite.com/service/ it will be (service.php or service123.php) .... and so on.

**Is it possible ? and if possible does it have any performance side effects ?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to place this directive in root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove extra trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}123.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1/$1123.php [L]
```

Comment: I think OP want to retrieve the current folder name dynamically in .htaccess. Is this actually possible what you think?

Comment: It is possible with some complicated rules but let's see what OP says.

Comment: Thanks guys for you response , but like Rahil said I want to do it at the root so I don't have to put an .htaccess file for every folder ?

Comment: I also want you to know the reason of my question , may be there is more simple solution : 1-I love the folder structure for websites.  2-I don't want all my site files name to be index.php for easier dealing.   I know there is ways in php rewrite urls but I'm not an php expert , any other solution ?

Comment: Do `products.php OR products123.php` exist in `/products/` directory OR at root level?

Comment: thanks a lot anubhava, but it doesn't work for me. Does this replace "DirectoryIndex" solution or it rewrite the address only ? After writing this in my .htaccess file I still have mysite.com/about-us/index.php working ,but mysite.com/products/products.php doesn't.

Comment: I mean that when I link to mysite.com/about-us/ it goes to index.php

Comment: And linking to mysite.com/products/ gives an 404 error.

Comment: `mysite.com/products/` will try to load `mysite.com/products/products.php` if it exists other it will try to load `mysite.com/products/products123.php` if that exists else no action. Does **`/products/products.php`** exist?

Comment: yes, mysite.com/products/products.php exist. Sorry for replying after 4 days, i had a problem in my internet.

Comment: Now I discovered the problem:I tried your code localy on my pc server (WAMP) it worked. But I can't make it work on the remote server , I think the problem is in %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} as the server can't define it.

Comment: Another thing I discovered that this code will work for first subfolders only : like Mysite.com/products but not for Mysite.com/products/product-One/ . is there any way to make it related to the requested folder not to the main root, so requesting any folder anywhere will return requestedfolder.php , Sorry for my many questions.

Comment: See updated rule, it should work for sub folders also.